# SQL how to use multiple joins on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm stuck with a tricky question that I'm unable to solve myself.
This is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: The desired output]

Is this even possible?
I tried following query already, but I'm not getting what I want.

```
SELECT t1.ID, info.start_bt1, info.start_bt2, t1.ANT as BT1_VL1, t2.ANT as BT1_VL2, t3.ANT as BT2_VL1, t4.ANT as BT2_VL2 
FROM antwoorden t1 
LEFT JOIN info ON t1.ID = info.ID 

LEFT JOIN antwoorden t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
AND t2.BT = 1 AND t2.VL = 2

LEFT JOIN antwoorden t3
ON t1.ID = t3.ID
AND t3.BT = 2 AND t3.VL = 1

LEFT JOIN antwoorden t4
ON t1.ID = t4.ID
AND t4.BT = 2 AND t4.VL = 2

WHERE t1.BT = 1 AND t1.VL = 1
```

The problem is I'm only getting the row with ID 2 (from the desired result). Does anyone know why I'm only getting the row with ID 2 and not all 4 of them?

---

Edit

I updated the picture so it's a bit clearer what I mean. Also, the ID is the ID given to a person. As you can see in the picture, this means that one person can have multiple rows. What I'm trying to do is to group all the data gathered from a person by their ID. I know this way is not a good way to store data, but I can't help it since somebody else made this, and I can't change it.

---

Another edit: here is [a sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f81b4/1)

Comment: It might help if you explain better what your tables actually mean and what you are trying to achieve. For example, it is unclear to me how you are collapsing 4 rows with id = 1 from the antwoorden table into the desired result table. What is the logic that you are intended to implement in doing this? Frankly it is not really even clear if your schema makes sense for how you are trying to work with this data.

Comment: It would be good if you can create [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Because of your WHERE clauses `WHERE t1.BT = 1 AND t1.VL = 1` you will never get ID 3 or 4 because there is no record with a BT and VL of 1 in your table for IDs 3 and 4. You'll have to rethink your approach for that one. I don't understand why you aren't getting ID of 1 though. That should come through since you are LJ'ing to everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it the other way round. Start with the `info` table and then `LEFT JOIN` multiple times to `antwoorden`:

```
select i.id,i.start_bt1,i.start_bt2,
a1.ant as "bt1_vl1",
a2.ant as "bt1_vl2",
a3.ant as "bt2_vl1",
a4.ant as "bt2_vl2"
from info i
left join antwoorden a1 on a1.id = i.id and a1.vl=1 and a1.bt=1
left join antwoorden a2 on a2.id = i.id and a2.vl=2 and a2.bt=1
left join antwoorden a3 on a3.id = i.id and a3.vl=1 and a3.bt=2
left join antwoorden a4 on a4.id = i.id and a4.vl=2 and a4.bt=2;
```